# Handling Buffering or Error Events in LibVLC when Video Data is Incomplete

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, video-streaming, libvlc

I'm utilizing `LibVLC` to play a video file alongside `MediaPlayer` and `VLCVideoLayout`. The video file is downloaded using segmented downloading where segments are fetched from both the start-to-middle and end-to-middle concurrently.

The playback operates smoothly until the video reaches a portion that hasn't been downloaded yet. In such instances, merely playing the video (without seeking) leads to an issue. The `setEventListener` of the `MediaPlayer` continuously emits `MediaPlayer.Event.TimeChanged` and `MediaPlayer.Event.PositionChanged` events (and returning `MediaPlayer.isPlaying` property true value), even when the video playback is halted and the video is just frozen in Android view. This behaviour suggests that the `MediaPlayer` internally believes the video is still playing despite the absence of the corresponding binary data in the file.

The sound btw may still playing when corresponding binary data become available in the file, but video remain forever frozen (this is not what I'm expecting it must be stopped together with the video playback).

For comparison, when using `ExoPlayer`, this issue doesn't arise. In scenarios where the content hasn't been downloaded, `ExoPlayer` either triggers a `Buffering` event or an `Error` event (indicating that the media source can't be read).

How can I emulate this behaviour in `libVLC`? Is there a way for the `setEventListener` to also trigger a `Buffering` event or any other event to indicate that the video playback is stuck?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
        @Composable
        private fun vlcView(): VLCVideoLayout {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            return remember {
                VLCVideoLayout(context).apply {
                    keepScreenOn = true
                    fitsSystemWindows = false
                    layoutParams =
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    
    @Composable
    private fun vlcLib(): LibVLC {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val lib = remember {
            LibVLC(context, ArrayList<String>().apply {
                add("--no-drop-late-frames")
                add("--no-skip-frames")
                add("--file-caching=1500")
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    add("-vvv")
                }
            })
        }
    
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            onDispose {
                lib.release()
            }
        }
    
        return lib
    }
    
    @Composable
    private fun vlcPlayer(vlcView: VLCVideoLayout, vlcLib: LibVLC): MediaPlayer {
        val player = remember {
            MediaPlayer(vlcLib).apply {
                attachViews(vlcView, null, true, false)
            }
        }
    
        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            onDispose {
                player.release()
            }
        }
    
        return player
    }

    private fun MediaPlayer.playMediaSource(vlcLib: LibVLC, source: Uri) {
        stop()
        Media(vlcLib, source).apply {
            setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false)
            media = this
        }.release()
        play()
    }
    


@Composable
fun MediaPlayer(downloadingMediaFile: File)
    val vlcView = vlcView()
    val vlcLib = vlcLib()
    val player = vlcPlayer(vlcView, vlcLib)
    
    AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                factory = {
                    vlcView
                }
            )
    
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
         player.setEventListener { event ->
            // Listening player events here...
         }
         player.playMediaSource(vlcLib, Uri.fromFile(downloadingMediaFile))
    }

}
```

libVLC version I use: `org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.5.1`

Some information about the file I tested:

**Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2**

**Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 720x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 1000 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn (default)**

**Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)**

The same issue I noticed when I using the VLC player on PC, it continues to play even if a portion of the video is missing from the file.

Comment: logs and an MCVE please

Comment: @mfkl where to get logs (how to filter it?) and where to get MCVE?